# NSDateComponents value was wrong when we convert NSDate to NSDate Components

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have faced the problem while convert the NsDate to NSDate Components for specific time region(France time zone) and specific month date(October 30,31). I suspect that this issue occurs due to day light saving time. Could please suggest how can i overcome this problem.
Please find my code snippet below,

```
public static NSDate GetDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int mins, int secs)
        {
            NSCalendar calendar = NSCalendar.CurrentCalendar;
            NSDate today = new NSDate();
            // Get the year, month, day from the date
            NSDateComponents startDateComponents = calendar.Components(
            NSCalendarUnit.Year | NSCalendarUnit.Month | NSCalendarUnit.Day, today);
            // Set the hour, minute, second
            startDateComponents.Year = year;
            startDateComponents.Month = month;
            startDateComponents.Day = date;
            startDateComponents.Hour = hour;
            startDateComponents.Minute = mins;
            startDateComponents.Second = secs;
            return calendar.DateFromComponents(startDateComponents);
        }

NSDate date = GetDate(2017, 10, 30, 6, 0, 0);
NSDateComponents dateComp= NSCalendar.CurrentCalendar.Components(NSCalendarUnit.Year | NSCalendarUnit.Month | NSCalendarUnit.Day | NSCalendarUnit.Hour ,date);
```

Where i have get the wrong dateComponents value except the October 30,31. Could you please suggest am i  missed any thing to convert the dates.

Comment: "i have get the wrong dateComponents" which one do you get?

Comment: I have get previous date value, for example if i set oct 30, i have get oct 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Son Thanh said , **timeZone** caused this issue.

However ,it still doesn't work when we set different timeZones ,we have to add the interval between GMT time manually.

Try the code as below.

```
public static NSDate GetDate(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int mins, int secs)
{
    NSCalendar calendar = NSCalendar.CurrentCalendar;
    NSDate today = new NSDate();
    // Get the year, month, day from the date
    NSDateComponents startDateComponents = calendar.Components(
    NSCalendarUnit.Year | NSCalendarUnit.Month | NSCalendarUnit.Day, today);
    // Set the hour, minute, second
    startDateComponents.Year = year;
    startDateComponents.Month = month;
    startDateComponents.Day = date;
    startDateComponents.Hour = hour;
    startDateComponents.Minute = mins;
    startDateComponents.Second = secs;

    NSDate d = calendar.DateFromComponents(startDateComponents);
    //interval between GMT and local timezone.
    nint interval = NSTimeZone.SystemTimeZone.SecondsFromGMT(d);
    //add the interval
    NSDate finalDate = d.AddSeconds(interval);
    return finalDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, might be you forgot set timeZone. Add this code:

```
calendar.timeZone = YourTimeZone
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have tried your solution still i get the wrong value after setting this timezone. It's wired thing to get the wrong dates for these specific dates. I can get the correct date value other than this october month.

Comment: There are many options when you used method DateFromComponents. I think it useful for you. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendaroptions?language=objc